# Merging less common levels of a factor in R into "Others"

Tags: r

I have a data frame, with a column State, with the values for all states ("Alabama, Alaska, Etc)

Is there a quick way to choose the top 10 more frequent states, and replace all the others by "Others"

I did it by summarising by frequency at the state level, creating an indicator

```
mutate(bottom_40 = ifelse frequency < x, TRUE,FALSE),
```

and then joining back and using logic to replace all the states with the indicator for 'others'.

This solution is just ugly, and I would appreciate if anyone could share a cleaner way to do that.

Answer (score 6):

`fct_lump_n` from `forcats` could help here. Consider this example :

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df <- data.frame(col = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:9], 
                 times = c(40, 10, 5, 27, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))))

df %>% count(col)

#  col  n
#1   A 40
#2   B 10
#3   C  5
#4   D 27
#5   E  1
#6   F  1
#7   G  1
#8   H  1
#9   I  1
```

Let's keep only top 3 levels and change rest of them to 'Other'.

```
df %>%
  mutate(col = fct_lump_n(col, 3)) %>%
  count(col)

#    col  n
#1     A 40
#2     B 10
#3     D 27
#4 Other 10
```